# Excel file handling using java

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I have been working on writing text files with Java. But now I want to know how to read and modify Excel files.  The reading part seems to be quite easy with [JExcel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) but I am stuck on modifying an Excel file. Any other methods are also welcome!!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: actually i want to know how to modify an existing excel file..

Answer (score 2):

Sample code for Writing excel using `Jexcel` is

```
public void write() throws IOException, WriteException {
    File file = new File(inputFile);
    WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

    wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
    workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
    WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
    createLabel(excelSheet);
    createContent(excelSheet);

    workbook.write();
    workbook.close();
}
```

For complete code for both reading and writing excel see [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html). Its very startup example for your requirement. And hope many example exists on this. Please do google on it further... Happy coding... :)

**Updated:**

For getting existing excel sheet replace three lines of new worksheet with below code: (Leaving above code as is, for information.)

```
Workbook existingWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(fileToEdit.getAbsolutePath()));
WritableWorkbook workbookCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"), existingWorkbook);
WritableSheet sheetToEdit = workbookCopy.getSheet(sheetName);
```

Please note it, this code is for reference, not compiled and tested. Provided as you asked for more information.... :)

Comment: actually i want to know how to modify an existing excel file..

Comment: logic will be same as in provided example for editing. But small change will be while passing excelsheet.. i.e. instead of creating new workbook, you will get existing workbook.. remaining all remains same..

Comment: Okay... for your clarity i'll edit some code, but not tested...

Comment: Is above answer informative for you now...

Comment: hey!!!...can u tell me how to post a code..i am new to it

Comment: if its correct accept the answer... it helps you to get good answers later... for entering code click {} in textarea...

Comment: ur code really helped me..i am done with modification..but now i want to know how to add color formats to the cell

Comment: If its the case, then why can't you accept the answer... ;)

Answer (score 0):

JExcel is designed for increased read efficiency (since this is the primary use of the API). In order to improve performance, data which relates to output information (eg. all the formatting information such as fonts) is not interpreted when the spreadsheet is read, since this is superfluous when interrogating the raw data values.

However, if we need to modify this spreadsheet a handle to the various write interfaces is needed, which can be obtained using the copy method.

The example is available [here](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html#copying%20and%20modifying). Refer the same.

Comment: I have downloaded  jxl.jar..but its giving some error..
cannot find symbol cell.setFormat(cellFormat);    
symbol:   method setFormat(WritableCellFormat)
location: variable cell of type WritableCell
Number is abstract; cannot be instantiated
Number number = new Number(3, 4, 3.1459);
 error: method addCell in interface WritableSheet cannot be applied to given types;
sheet2.addCell(number); 

  required: WritableCell
  found: Number
  reason: actual argument Number cannot be converted to WritableCell by method invocation conversion
3 errors

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use below jars for reading and creating Excel document.

Required jars
poi-3.8-20120326.jar

poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar

poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar

xbean.jar

dom4j-1.6.1.jar

For more help please visit :

http://javabraiins.blogspot.in/2012/12/read-excel-file-in-java.html