# Excel File manipulation

Tags: java, jexcelapi

How to add Color formats to the excel cells using JExcel API.I have an existing excel file and want how to add color format to the desired cell

Comment: It would be helpful to see your effort.

Answer (score 1):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290238/excel-file-handling-using-java/14290357#14290357) for `modifying the excel cells using JExcel API`. That answer is provided for you only :)

---

For adding color formats to excel cells try the below code.

```
// Create cell font and format
private static WritableCellFormat getCellFormat(Colour colour, Pattern pattern) throws WriteException {
    WritableFont cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 16);
    WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
    cellFormat.setBackground(colour, pattern);
    return cellFormat;
}
```

---

```
// Create the label, specifying content and format
Label label = new Label(1, 2, "ABC", getCellFormat(Colour.GREEN, Pattern.GRAY_25));
Label label2 = new Label(1, 4, "PQR", getCellFormat(Colour.BLUE, Pattern.GRAY_50));
Label label3 = new Label(1, 6, "XYZ", getCellFormat(Colour.ORANGE, Pattern.GRAY_75));

sheet.addCell(label);
sheet.addCell(label2);
sheet.addCell(label3);
```

getting `sheet` is already provided in above link..